# Merging hashes inside of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, mongodb, hash

Uing Ruby (1.8.7) and Mongo Driver, I've written this:

```
@data['Users'] = []
@database['user_facilities'].find({ :facility_id => @facility['id'] }).each do |user_facility|
  @data['Users'] << @database['users'].find({ :id => user_facility['user_id'] }).to_a
end
```

Which outputs:

```
[ "Users", [ [ { "name" => "michael" }, { "name" => "dennis" } ], [ { "name" => "brandon" }, { "name" => "steve" } ] ] ]
```

But I'd like it to look like this:

```
[ "Users", [ { "name" => "michael" }, { "name" => "dennis" }, { "name" => "brandon" }, { "name" => "steve" } ] ]
```

I understand why I get the results I do above. I've tried "flatten" and "merge." But nothing seems to return data as I want it.

Comment: [array[0], array[1].flatten(1)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@database['user_facilities'].find({ :facility_id => @facility['id'] }).each do |user_facility|
  @data['Users'].push *@database['users'].find({ :id => user_facility['user_id'] }).to_a
end
```